# Python doesn't iterate through nested loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a nested loop inside a function that does not seem to be working.

Both the keys and values of the 'broadcast' dictionary exist (are non-empty) and print to stdout.

When I try to print out in a loop (the second loop) what I think should be broadcast's values, it is empty - this does not make sense to me because I clearly see them printed out from the first loop when I use

```
print(broadcast.values())
```

The first chunk below is my code and following it is what is printed out to stdout: ( ... displayed where output continues)

```
def broadcast_display(results):
    broadcast = results['broadcast']
    thumbnails = results['thumbnails']
    html = []
    html.append('\n<h2 style="text-align:center;">Broadcast / Receive</h2>')
    message = ""
    print('broadcasts keys')
    print(broadcast.keys())
    print('broadcasts values')
    print(broadcast.values())
    for type, lists in broadcast.items():
        print('looping through broadcasts values')
        print(lists)                                                                               
        for list in lists:
            #Does not reach this loop                                                               
            print('TEST 3: does not print')
            #code goes on
            html.append('\n<hr>')
            html.append('\n<h2>{0}</h2>'.format(KelpPlugin.SCRIPT_TITLES[blocktype])) #heading                          
            html.append('\n<table border = "1">')
            for sprite, script in blocklist:
                if KelpPlugin.script_start_type(script) == KelpPlugin.HAT_WHEN_I_RECEIVE:
                    # check if the message is the same as the last one                                                  
                    # if it is, print this script next to the last                                                      
                    # otherwise, print it below the last                                                                
                    if message != script[0].args[0].lower():
                        html.append('\n  </tr>')
                        html.append('\n  <tr>')
                    message = script[0].args[0].lower()
                    script_images = KelpPlugin.to_scratch_blocks(sprite, script)
                    html.append('\n<td>')
                    html.append('\n<p>        {0}</p>'.format(sprite))
                    html.append('\n    <p><img src="{0}" height="100" width="100"></p>'.format(thumbnails[sprite]))
                    html.append('\n<pre class="blocks">')
                    html.append('\n<p>{0}</p>'.format(script_images))
                    html.append('\n</pre>')
                    html.append('\n</td>')
                elif KelpPlugin.script_start_type != KelpPlugin.NO_HAT:
                    if message == "":
                        html.append('\n  </tr>')
                    html.append('\n  <tr>')
                    script_images = KelpPlugin.to_scratch_blocks(sprite, script)
                    html.append('\n<p>{0}</p>'.format(sprite))
                    html.append('\n    <p><img src="{0}" height="100" width="100></p>'.format(thumbnails[sprite]))
                    html.append('\n<pre class="blocks">')
                    html.append('\n<p>{0}</p>'.format(script_images))
                    html.append('\n</pre>')
                    html.append('\n  </tr>')
            html.append('\n</table>')
            return ''.join(html)

broadcasts keys
[0, 2, 3]
broadcasts values
[[], [[(u'LosAngeles', kurt.Script([
    kurt.Block('whenClicked'), ...
looping through broadcasts values
[]
```

The results dictionary looks like this:

```
{0: [], 2: [[(u'San Juan Batista', kurt.Script([
kurt.Block('whenClicked'),
kurt.Block('broadcast:', u'SJB')], pos=(69, 59.0))), (u'Missionary', kurt.Script([
kurt.Block('whenIReceive', u'SJB'), ... 3: []}
```

Also this is my first time asking a question on StackOverflow so go easy on me please :)

Comment: your first value is empty list so it's not printed, does your code print second item `[[(uu'LosAngeles'...`?

Comment: `type` and `list` are built-in functions that you're overriding (for the duration of `broadcast_display`) with your `for` loops.  It's not clear whether this relates to the failure, which appears to have something to do with something not shown here.

Comment: The output and the code do not match. It should print `looping through broadcasts key value pairs`. Please, write the *actual* code and output that you get.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @Bakuriu You are correct they don't match. It was my code (now changed to the correct version) that was incorrect. I typed that part out (incorrectly) because I was having issues with copy / pasting from my editor. I now know to not do that.

Comment: Thanks @torek. I tried changing `type` and `list` to different names, but it did not have any effect on my output

Comment: @RomanPekar that is an interesting thing to note. It only prints out the first empty list `[]` and not the second item `[[uu'LosAngeles'...`

Comment: @DavidBorden Yes, I noticed that as well. Which mean that somewhere after the part `#code goes on`, you prematurely exit the (outer) loop. You'll have to show that part of the code as well, because *that's* where things go wrong.

Comment: I have now displayed the full code for my function.

Comment: The first iteration of the loop seems correct -- the first value of `lists` is `[]` so the loop doesn't execute that time, just as it shouldn't. For subsequent loops -- do you have this code wrapped in a `try / except` block that could be hiding a syntax error or other error?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with a sample code and I am able to reach the inner loop. Here:

```
di = {'0': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], '2': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'], '3': 'c'}
for k,v in di.items():
    print k
    for item in v:
        print "\t" + item
```

Output:

```
$ python t.py
0
    a1
    a2
    a3
3
    c
2
    b1
    b2
    b3
$
```

The values that you specify seem to not have a properly formed loop. Can you check that. As per the key/values that you have provided, here is how your dictionary should look like? Can you please specify that properly.

```
0: [[], 
2: [[(u'LosAngeles', kurt.Script([
    kurt.Block('whenClicked'), 
3: ... looping through broadcasts values []
```

Comment: @Manoy Pandey I have changed my post to include the dictionary. Thank you.